# get a point after rotating the rectangle

Tags: java, math

I got a sprite, I know the position, and the rectangle behind.
I want to get the location behind the sprite, I know the offset.

My point would be like:

```
Point p=new Point(sprite.getX()-offset,sprite.getY()-sprite.getHeight()/2);
```

If I rotate my sprite around its center origin, I want to get the new location of that point.

An image that will explain better:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the coordinates of the rotation center (the point which remains fixed).

```
X' = (X - Xc) * cos(A) - (Y - Yc) * sin(A) + Xc
Y' = (Y - Yc) * cos(A) + (X - Xc) * sin(A) + Yc
```

And it would also be nice to tell us what does not work, as you don't give a clue...

Comment: (I am using this but not getting proper) double sx = ((line.getStartX() - circle.getCenterX()) * Math
    .cos(rotation))
    - ((line.getStartY() - circle.getCenterY()) * Math
      .sin(rotation)) + circle.getCenterX();

Comment: @Jay: This comment also applies to you: "And it would also be nice to tell us what does not work, as you don't give a clue..."

Comment: I just want to know 2 things 1) How to get angle and 2) This angle in radiant or degree

Comment: 1) How to get angle: from what givens ??? 2) This angle in radiant or degree: like Math requires

Comment: I used this in Game Maker Studio 2, but I had to do (360-angle) and then convert degrees to radians, otherwise it rotates in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Lokiare: yep, that depends on the orientation of your axes. -angle will also work.

Answer (score 1):

See the source of Sprite on Libgdx on **getVertices()**, there is calculation but in local, that might help.

This like is very useful

http://www.philvaz.com/games/rotate.htm

```
xnew = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
ynew = y * cos(angle) + x * sin(angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the documentation of the [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) class as well as any number of sources on Wolfram MathWorld or Wikipedia (e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationFormula.html). In Java, your sprite will probably be rendered in a rotated frame using the `AffineTransform` class, so if you apply your transformations carefully, you may not even have to do any extra math yourself to get the position of the trailing point.

Answer (score 0):

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/ in this api, the sprite class has a method to get the rotation, look if that documentation is useful