# How to find the points of contact of a line with the boundaries of the canvas after rotating the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I'm not good at geometry, so it would be easier for me to just see the formula and understand how it works.  I need a formula in Javascript so that I can find the point after rotating the canvas.

```
<canvas width="910" height="300"></canvas>

canvas{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    outline:1px solid red;
}


let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.clientWidth;
let h = canvas.clientHeight;

let line_width = 1;
let degrees = 0;
let rad = 0;

ctx.lineWidth = line_width;
ctx.setLineDash([5,20]);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

let x_1 = w/2;
let y_1 = h/2;

let x_2 = w;
let y_2 = h;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x_1, y_1);
ctx.lineTo(x_2, y_2);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.translate(w/2,h/2);
degrees += 45;
rad = degrees * (Math.PI/180);  
ctx.rotate(rad);
ctx.translate(-w/2,-h/2);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x_1, y_1);
// Find the coordinates of the point and draw a line.
//x_2 = ?
//y_2 = ?
```

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c03AD.png)]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888975/get-a-point-after-rotating-the-rectangle

Answer (score 0):

It's decided. The question is closed. This helped me: [Finding points on a rectangle at a given angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061576/finding-points-on-a-rectangle-at-a-given-angle)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).